# Drupal Search API (Solr): How to add items from csv to index?

Tags: solr, drupal

I have a basic CSV in form:

| id | title | body | url |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| qwertyu | External Article 1 | External content summary 1 | https://externaldomain.com/link-to-article-1 |

I need to add this to existing Search API (Solr) index, so when site search is used those items also appear.

Could somebody please explain step-by-step what needs to be done to achieve that on Drupal 10 (Solr 8)?

I tried creating a Custom Datasource `class MyCustomDatasource extends DatasourcePluginBase implements DatasourceInterface`, could see 'My Custom Datasource' in the list of data sources but got stuck for the following reasons:

- `loadMultiple(array $ids)` receives `null`, what passes `$ids` to it?
- Even if I account for null $ids and force return all `$items` then it recognises that there's `items indexed 0/n` but when I click 'Index Now' it fails with error ~ 'Could not find datasource with ID '' (empty ID)

Does datasource actually add items to index or does it only consume existing items in index (solr)?

I also tried using 'Solr Document' as datasource, added an item directly to Solr server, set `ss_search_api_id` to **'solr_document/qwertyu:en'** and `ss_search_api_datasource` to **'sold_document'** but it doesn't seem to 'see'/recognise the new item because it says `items indexed (0/0)`